# Vue dynamic class based on props array length

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to add a class to an element in a Vue component based on the count of an array in the props. The `categories` array is passed in from the parent component.

```
<template>
    <div
        :class="{ 'isOpen': open, 'show': categoriesCount > 0 }"
    >
        …
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        categories: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            open: false,
            categoriesCount: {...this.categories.length}
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

With the above the `show` doesn't display even though the categories array has items. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ ...this.categories.length }` is non-sensical.  You're [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) a number (`categories.length`), which you can't do, and putting it inside object without a key (objects contain key-value pairs).  The result is just an empty object. Then your v-if is checking if this empty object is greater than 0, which is again non-sensical although JavaScript does provide an answer (it's false).  Plus, this data variable is not reactive to prop changes.

The easiest solution is to just use `categories.length` directly in the template.

```html
<div
  :class="{ 'isOpen': open, 'show': categories.length > 0 }"
>
```

Otherwise, if you want slightly cleaner template code you could use a [computed](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed) property that simply returns `categories.length`. As a computed property it will be reactive to the prop `categories` changing in length.

```js
export default {
  props: {
    categories: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    categoriesCount() {
      return this.categories.length
    }
  }
}
```